# codeigniter changes the results of the foreach into an array

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

I have an output like the one below, how do you loop the results into an array?

```
16
PT. QWERT
62218501053
JL. MAYJEN SUTOYO

16
PT. ABCD
62218501053
JL. MAYJEN SUTOYO
```

how to change into this ?

```
Array
(
    [id_cs] => 16
    [nama] => PT. QWERT
    [tlp] => 87878
    [alamat_detail] => JL. MAYJEN SUTOYO
)
1

Array
(
    [id_cs] => 16
    [nama] => PT. ABCD
    [tlp] => 123
    [alamat_detail] => JL. MAYJEN SUTOYO 
)
1
```

This my code

```
$array = array(
    'id_cs' => $row['AN'],
    'nama' => $row['AO'],
    'tlp' => $row['AP'],
    'alamat_detail' => $row['AQ'],
);
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value))
        unset($array[$key]);
}
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo($array[$key]."<br>");
}  
//$this->db->insert('customer_address',$array);
```

how to implement the code? thank you for answering

Comment: _I have an output_ Output from what, please tell us how that _output_ is generated

Comment: i have the output output from $ _POST and i "<pre>"

Comment: So show us a `print_r($_POST);` Put the output into the question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60267242/edit) link

Answer (score 0):

Write this code.

```
$array[] = array(
'id_cs' => $row['AN'],
'nama' => $row['AO'],
'tlp' => $row['AP'],
'alamat_detail' => $row['AQ'] );

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
if (empty($value))
    unset($array[$key]); }

foreach($array as $row){
$this->db->insert('customer_address',$row); }
```